# When does CBO compiler use Range scan in oracle?

Tags: oracle10g

When does CBO compiler use Range scan in oracle??

Answer (score 3):

When there's a suitable index on the table - and the calculated cost of the plan is the least (or if the query is hinted to scan the index).